# retrieve first 6 words from string php

Tags: php

I have this string in php

```
 $string="lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-elit-sed-do-eiusmod-tempor-incididunt-ut-labore-et-dolore-magna-aliqua";
```

I want to retrive just the six first words between `-`, in this case

```
  function retrieve6firstWords($string){


    return $string;
    }

 echo retrieve6firstWords($string); //$string= "lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur";
```

How can I do this?

Comment: your link gets the string from a sentence. In this case it comes from a friendly url...Can you makr it as duplicate with some other question like this?

Comment: The source of the string does not matter. You can very easily alter the other solution to fit your needs especially since you just plan to implement a `retrieve6firstWords()` function.

Answer (score 0):

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) by -, [slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) to only 6 and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) back into a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
<?php
$string = "lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur-adipiscing-elit-sed-do-eiusmod-tempor-incididunt-ut-labore-et-dolore-magna-aliqua";

$words = explode('-', $string);

$words = array_slice($words, 0, 6);

$string = implode('-', $words);

print_r($string);
```

**Result:**

```
lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet-consectetur
```

https://3v4l.org/YtVrE

If you want the words and not a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) they are in the [array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php), just don't [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it.